# Weblinks module from Joomla 1.5 for Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

We are upgrading a client's old Joomla 1.5 website to Joomla 3. They heavily used the Weblinks component (Web Link Manager) that came with Joomla 1.5 for managing links.

Is there the equivalent for Joomla 3? Or another method that's used currently to manage links in Joomla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the **Official Component** from the extensions directory, here you have the link:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/official-extensions/weblinks